# при распаковки zip ошибка java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

При распаковки zip архива бесконечная ошибка  java.io.FileNotFoundException:
И распаковывает только файлы папки не распаковывает
**Метод распаковки unZip**

**Class ArchiveApp**

```
 public class ArchiveApp {

        private File baseDir;
        private int position;
        private byte[] buf;
        private ZipOutputStream zos;
        public static final String un_Zip = "C:\\Users\\Pivar\\OneDrive\\Документы\\NetBeansProjects\\Home_Work_JavaZIP\\archiveApp.zip";
        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

        public ArchiveApp(String baseAdr) {
            this.baseDir = new File(baseAdr);
            position = baseDir.getParent().length() + File.separator.length();
            // System.out.println(baseDir.getAbsolutePath().substring(position) + File.separator);
            buf = new byte[4096];
        }

        public void create() {
            File zipFile = new File(baseDir.getParent(), baseDir.getName() + ".zip");
            try (ZipOutputStream z = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile))) {
                zos = z;
                pass(baseDir);
                zos.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ArchiveApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        private void pass(File dir) {
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                addEntry(zos, file);
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    pass(file);
                }
            }
        }

        private void addEntry(ZipOutputStream zos, File file) {
            try {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(formEntryName(file));
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                        int count;
                        while ((count = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                            zos.write(buf, 0, count);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        private String formEntryName(File file) {
            String res = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(position);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                res = res + File.separator;
            }
            return res;
        }

        public void unZip(final String zipFileName) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            final String dstDirectory = destinationDirectory(zipFileName);
            final File dstDir = new File(dstDirectory);
            if (!dstDir.exists()) {
                dstDir.mkdirs();
            }
            try {
                final ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(zipFileName));
                ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                String nextFileName;
                while (ze != null) {
                    nextFileName = ze.getName();
                    File nextFile = new File(dstDirectory + File.separator
                            + nextFileName);
                    System.out.println("Un-zip " + nextFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                        nextFile.mkdirs();
                    } else {
                        new File(nextFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
                        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nextFile)) {
                            int lenght;
                            while ((lenght = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                            }
                            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                            zis.closeEntry();
                            zis.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        private String destinationDirectory(final String srcZip) {
            return srcZip.substring(0, srcZip.lastIndexOf("."));
        }
```

**Main**

```
public class Home_Work_JavaZIP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArchiveApp app = new ArchiveApp("C:\\Users\\Pivar\\OneDrive\\Документы\\NetBeansProjects\\Home_Work_JavaZIP\\archiveApp");
        //app.create();
        app.unZip(un_Zip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет возможности проверить ваш код, но есть пример рабочего кода из одного из проектов. Возможно чем то поможет:

```
public static void unzipFile(File zipFile, File destinationFolder) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            String filename = zipEntry.getName();
            File newFile = new File(destinationFolder + File.separator + filename);
            if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                newFile.mkdir();
                if (rootDir == null) {
                    rootDir = newFile;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```